# How to remove a 'bullet ' sprite after it has reached mouseX and mouseY? [P5.Play]

Tags: p5.js

I'm making a game using P5.Play, where I have 3 obelisks; one on the left, one on the right and one in the middle. I have made it so if my mouse position is within a specific area of the canvas, the obelisk nearest will shoot towards my mouse position. However I am struggling to find a way to get the sprite to explode once it has reached the x and y point at which when I clicked the mouse. I won't post my full code because it's for an assignment but here is a snippet.

```
function mousePressed() { 
    if (mouseX < width / 3) {
        bullet = createSprite(obelisks[0].position.x, obelisks[0].position.y - 60, 20, 20)
    } else if (mouseX > width / 3 && mouseX < width - width / 3) {
        bullet = createSprite(obelisks[1].position.x, obelisks[1].position.y - 60, 20, 20)
    } else {
        bullet = createSprite(obelisks[2].position.x, obelisks[2].position.y - 60, 20, 20)
    }

    // if bullet position is less than the distance between firing point and cursor position, then remove bullet??

    bullet.addImage(bulletSprite);
    bullet.attractionPoint(10, mouseX, mouseY);
    bullet.rotateToDirection = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, thank you for introducing me to p5.play!

There's a couple of things to think about here, but you're very close. From [reading the documentation](http://molleindustria.github.io/p5.play/docs/classes/Sprite.html) there's a function on the `sprite` object called `overlapPoint(pointX, pointY)` which:

> Checks if the given point is inside the sprite's collider.

This returns a boolean. We can leverage this to determine if our bullet has reached its destination.

First of all, let's define the `destinationX` and `destinationY` properties on our object:

```js
function mousePressed() {
  ...
  bullet = createSprite(width/2, height, 10, 10);
  let destinationX = mouseX;
  let destinationY = mouseY;
  
  bullet.attractionPoint(10, destinationX, destinationY);
  bullet.destinationX = destinationX;
  bullet.destinationY = destinationY;
}
```

Now, we can use these properties to determine if we've hit the overlap point:

```js
function draw() {
  background(220);
  drawSprite(obelisk);
  
  if (bullet) {
    drawSprite(bullet);
    if (bullet.overlapPoint(bullet.destinationX, bullet.destinationY)) {
      bullet.remove();
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a working, simplified example:

```js
let obelisk;
let bullet;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  obelisk = createSprite(width/2, height, 50, 200);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  drawSprite(obelisk);
  
  if (bullet) {
    drawSprite(bullet);
    if (bullet.overlapPoint(bullet.destinationX, bullet.destinationY)) {
      bullet.remove();
    }
  }
}


function mousePressed() {
  bullet = createSprite(width/2, height, 10, 10);
  let destinationX = mouseX;
  let destinationY = mouseY;
  
  bullet.attractionPoint(10, destinationX, destinationY);
  bullet.destinationX = destinationX;
  bullet.destinationY = destinationY;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/molleindustria/p5.play/lib/p5.play.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here's a link to a [p5.js sketch I created](https://editor.p5js.org/codeheir/sketches/ytvK0Ra5A), to help you further.

Hopefully, this points you in the right direction. I might also recommend that you create an array of bullets, such: `let bullets = []` and add to this array when you shoot, this would prevent the deletion of a bullet when shooting in rapid succession. Or you could maybe even look into p5.play's [grouping object](http://molleindustria.github.io/p5.play/docs/classes/Group.html#method-add).

Comment: Thank you Luke! This seems like what I was looking for. I think you're right, I will need to make a group so the bullets don't disappear upon multiple clicks, but that shouldn't be too hard to figure out!